# Mapping TimeSpan to DateTime using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have a legacy DB that stores a time using a DateTime, and I'm trying to get AutoMapper to map a TimeSpan to it.

The Date part does not matter, and it's set to min the smallest available (DateTime.MinValue).

The mapping I'm using is

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.InceptionTime, 
            opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.InceptionTime == null ? default(DateTime?) : DateTime.MinValue.Add(s.InceptionTime.Value)))
```

In the source the InceptionTime is a TimeSpan? and in the destination it is a DateTime?

When running the code I get this error:

> Mapping types: TimeSpan -> Nullable`1 System.TimeSpan ->
>   System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>
> Destination path: MyEntitySection.InceptionTime.InceptionTime
>
> Source value:
>   -10675199.02:48:05.4775808

What am I missing?

Comment: are you using queryable extensions.  I.E. `ProjectTo`?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware

Comment: Show us the full line of code that you're using to map the configuration, including the stuff before `.ForMember` and also show us what class you're actually mapping to

Comment: This value is `TimeSpan.MinValue` (which is `new TimeSpan(long.MinValue)`). It is notably not `default(TimeSpan)`, so something interesting is going on when it's retrieved.